# kml load text label with markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an external kml feed that I correctly have showing approx 400 markers on the Google map.  However, I would like to display the Placemark/name field onload (which is just a 4-digit number) with every marker.  I can't seem to find a good resource on how to accomplish this.  Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your KML look like?  Sounds like it is simple enough that a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) might let you do what you want.   [example of "sidebar" from KML using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_cta_test.html)

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for the quick reply!  I've been trying to use geoxml3 to load the kml.  But it's having fits due to the kml being at an external url.  Thoughts???

var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({ map: mymap });
        myParser.parse("https://www.domain.com/data.kml");

Comment: FYI: The .parse method has the entire https : //www.domain.com/data.kml path... not sure why the last comment snipped it...

Comment: If the KML is at an external URL, you will need to load it via a [proxy](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml/wiki/Proxy).

Comment: @geocodezip the proxy trick was what I was missing!  Thank you!!!  Can't mark this answered from these comments though.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the KML is at an external URL, you will need to load it via a [proxy](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml/wiki/Proxy).

Comment: I guess I forgot about the rest of my issue.  Now that I have the kml loading correctly.  Would you know how to display text labels onload of the markers?  So I want each marker to have a label showing with a 4-digit number from the <name> element.

I've seen examples (such as http://www.tdmarketing.co.nz/blog/2011/03/09/create-marker-with-custom-labels-in-google-maps-api-v3/) but none that are tied to kml integration...    Any help?  Thanks again

Comment: What does your code look like where you attempted to do that?

Comment: I haven't tried yet...  I assume I would have to loop through each Placemark in the kml after it has loaded?  Is that what I would use geoxml3 for?  (Sorry I'm very new with the gmaps api)